# How to enforce order of execution of KafkaListeners

Tags: spring-kafka

I have several classes annotated as @KafkaListener. The goal is to enforce order of execution of these listeners, so that one of them is always executed last. I have tried Order annotation, but it had no effect. I would like to avoid any manual synchronization, and enforce it via Spring methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed last"? They are independent of each other and once initialized the containers invoke the listeners whenever messages arrive.

Comment: It might be good to show the relevant code so that we provide you with a good answer